# variable keeps getting updated without any code that says to

Tags: javascript, html

I have two variables in a sandbox based game.

```
blocks
```

(array)

and

```
blockssave
```

(also array)

but i also have these functions:

```
var game = {
    blocksave: function() {
        blockssave = blocks;
        blockserasedsave = blockserased;
    },
    blockload: function() {
        blocks = blockssave;
        blockserased = blockserasedsave;
    },
    blockreset: function() {
        blocks = [];
        blockserased = 0;
    }
}
```

if I call blocksave once, it keeps getting saved until I reset
so if I save then keep building then load, the loaded world is just like it was AFTER i saved AND builded some more. If I reset, though, it stops saving until I game.blockload(). I even tried the functions being defined inside a button onclick.

I have looked through my code and the save function is only called when the button is pressed. (I tested that)

The only clue is a function being called over and over to run the game. (save is not inside it)

Answer (score 1):

`blockssave = blocks` does not copy the array. It just points the blockssave reference to the same blocks array.

If the elements of the array are primitives, you can quickly make a shallow copy of the blocks array like this:

`blockssave = blocks.slice(0);`

If the elements are objects, then you need to deep copy the array by looping over it and making a new object for each element.

Comment: I will make sure to try that! Thanks!

Comment: The code is now: var game = {
    blocksave: function() {
        blockssave = blocks.slice(0);
        blockserasedsave = blockserased;
    },
    blockload: function() {
        blocks = blockssave.slice(0);
        blockserased = blockserasedsave;
    },
    blockreset: function() {
        blocks = [];
        blockserased = 0;
    }
} but it still did not work

Comment: What are the elements of the array? If they are objects or other arrays, you need to deep copy using a loop.